# haproxy tcp-request content reject unless Layer 7

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to configure HAProxy to reject HTTP requests on Layer 4 unless the URL path requests use starts with a configured prefix.

It works fine on Layer 7 but I cannot get it work on Layer 4.

I've tried quite a few of combinations and couldn't anything to work. Please find below the smallest example of what I would expect to work:

- Run in HTTP mode
- Build an ACL basing on a prefix of path
- Reject on Layer 4 if that prefix doesn't exist

The thing is, requests are always rejected, no matter the prefix.

The way I understand the documentation, if no ACL matches, the default
course of action is to allow the request.

Hence it would seem that:

- Either I'm mistaken on the default behaviour
- The ACL always matches regardless of the prefix

But I'm not really sure, could you please help me out with it?

Thank you!

```
************************************************************

defaults
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout client  3000
    timeout server  3000

backend bck_static1
    mode http
    server server1 example.com:80 check inter 2s rise 2 fall 2

frontend front_static1

    mode http
    default_backend bck_static1

    acl required_prefix path_beg /hello
    tcp-request content reject unless required_prefix

    option forwardfor
    option httpclose

    bind 0.0.0.0:22334

************************************************************

HA-Proxy version 1.4.24 2013/06/17
HA-Proxy version 1.5.12 2015/05/02

************************************************************

$ haproxy -d -V -f haproxy1.conf
Available polling systems :
     sepoll : pref=400,  test result OK
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 4 (3 usable), will use sepoll.
Using sepoll() as the polling mechanism.


00000000:front_static1.accept(0004)=0005 from [127.0.0.1:53110]
00000000:front_static1.clicls[0005:ffff]
00000000:front_static1.closed[0005:ffff]


00000001:front_static1.accept(0004)=0005 from [127.0.0.1:53112]
00000001:front_static1.clicls[0005:ffff]
00000001:front_static1.closed[0005:ffff]

^C
$ 

************************************************************

$ curl -v 127.0.0.1:22334/abc
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 22334 (#0)
> GET /abc HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:22334
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

************************************************************

$ curl -v localhost:22334/hello
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 22334 (#0)
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:22334
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ 

************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI - it was answered on the HAProxy's mailing list.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/21962

One needs to add `tcp-request inspect-delay` so that HAProxy has a chance to inspect the incoming request at all.

Setting `tcp-request inspect-delay 10s` did the trick nicely.